# What is wrong with the structure of my 'BrowserRouter', 'Routes' and 'Route' in my function App()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am attempting to follow a tutorial while learning React.JS and I am running into an issue because the tutorial is using an older version of React and I am stuck trying to figure out how to use **BrowserRouter**, **Routes**, and **Route**.

Can anyone assist me in trying to re-structure the code so it works with the updated version of React? I have tried reading through documentation and tried to mix around a few solutions with no success. Any help is much appreciated!

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component.js";
import PortfolioList from "./components/portfolio-list.component";
import EditPortfolio from "./components/edit-portfolio.component";
import CreatePortfolio from "./components/create-portfolio.component";
import CreateUser from "./components/create-user.component";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Navbar />
      <br/>
      <Route path="/" exact component={PortfolioList} />
      <Route path="/edit/:id" exact component={EditPortfolio} />
      <Route path="/create" exact component={CreatePortfolio} />
      <Route path="/user" exact component={CreateUser} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The following is the 'error' I'm generating on runtime:

> Error: [Navbar] is not a 'Route' component. All component children of
> 'Routes' must be a 'Route' or 'React.Fragment'

Answer (score 0):

Only `Route` components and `React.Fragment`s can be a child of the `Routes` component, and vice-versa. Move the non-`Route` components out of `Routes`. The `Route` component API also changed in version 6, there is no longer `render` and `component` props, the routed components are passed to the `element` prop ***as*** JSX, and routes are now ***always*** exactly matched, so there's no longer the `exact` prop as well.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <br/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<PortfolioList />} />
        <Route path="/edit/:id" element={<EditPortfolio />} />
        <Route path="/create" element={<CreatePortfolio />} />
        <Route path="/user" element={<CreateUser />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "BrowserRouter" tag followed by the "Switch" tag then you can now use the "Route" tag to specify the path of each component

Comment: FYI, it appears that OP is using version 6 of `react-router-dom` so there is no exported `Switch` component.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "BrowserRouter" tag followed by the "Switch" tag then you can now use the "Route" tag to specify the path of each component.

`````
    return (
        <>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={DashBoard} />
                    <Route path="/specialistes" exact component={Specialistes} />
                    <Route path="/findgarages" exact component={FindGarage} />
                    <Route path="/garages" exact component={Garages} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </>
    )````
`````